# merge unregistered account with this one

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I have an account that I sued to post my first question. I did it partly because I just wanted to quickly answer a question and partly because I wanted to be anonymous. Well, I don't care about being anonymous. I think I can stand up for anything I said in my question. The account is "John" which I used to ask [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5430/what-went-wrong-project-going-off-track).

Is there anyway these two accounts can be merged?

If not that's fine. It's just one question and I'm sure I'll be asking many more around here.

Comment: Hi Ryan, we merged your other account into this one. Thanks for letting us know to merge them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of us will work on getting your john account merged into your Ryan Muller account. You can continue to use your Ryan Muller account in the meantime until we get this fixed.

Welcome to Project Management SE!